# Adding if does not exist otherwise insert

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am working in a project where I need to save data to different tables using Entity Framework.
I am actually saving addresses.

My tables are:

Address (Id, address line1, StateId, SuburbId, PostcodeId)
State (Id, StateName)
Suburb (Id, SuburbName)
Postcode (Id, PO)

How can I insert a new address and, if the postcode and / or Suburb exists in the table, use the existing one for the new address, otherwise insert the new suburb / postcode into the related tables.
For instance, a new address is being inserted, but the suburb already exists in the suburb table, therefore I need a constraint to the existing one, instead of creating (duplicating) the suburb in the suburb table.

Does it make sense? I have not tried anything because I don't have a clue on what to try.

This is what I have so far:

```
Entities db = new Entities();

var addrSuburb = new Suburb()
{
    SuburbName = "My Suburb"
};

var addrState = new State()
{
    State1 = "My State",
    StateShort = "MS"
};
var addrPostCode = new Postcode()
{
    PO = 4234
}
var addrCust = new Address()
{
    AddressLine1 = My address,
    Suburb1 = addrSuburb,
    Postcode1 = addrPostCode,
    State = addrState
};

db.Postcodes.Add(addrPostCode);
db.Suburbs.Add(addrSuburb);
db.States.Add(addrState);                        
db.Addresses.Add(addrCust);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If I could have a small example, that would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the right way to save and restore a disconnected entity using code first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787306/what-is-the-right-way-to-save-and-restore-a-disconnected-entity-using-code-first)

Comment: does each of table has any unique id or primary key | any of this table has unique/primary key?

Comment: Hi Leez, yes they do. They are related StateId, SuburbId and PostcodeId are the ids of the correspondent table. They have foreign key contraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make a decision weather it should be Insert or Update according to SuburbName in 
Suburb table you can do this as follows.

```
if(!db.Suburbs.where(x=>x.SuburbName.Equel(addrSuburb.SuburbName)).ToList().Count > 0)
{
// Insert Flow
db.Postcodes.Add(addrPostCode);
db.Suburbs.Add(addrSuburb);
db.States.Add(addrState);                        
db.Addresses.Add(addrCust);

}
else
{
  // Update Flow

db.Postcodes.Attach(addrPostCode);
db.Suburbs.Attach(addrSuburb);
db.States.Attach(addrState);
db.Addresses.Attach(addrCust);

db.Entry(addrPostCode).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(addrSuburb).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(addrState).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(addrCust).State = EntityState.Modified;

}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This looks interesting Leez. I will try that. However i dont actually need to update existing data, just use it. For instance, a new address is going to use an existing suburb (MySuburb), so I need to find the Id of the MySuburb record in the Suburb table and set it in the column SuburbId of the Address table. However if it is the first time that someone is inserting that suburb (MySuburb), then it needs to be recorded in the Suburb table and pass the new id to the Address table (column SuburbId). Would the db.table.Attach be equivalent to .add(object)? many thanks mate

Comment: oh my bad no need to attach within the insert flow

Comment: Hey Leez, but I still don't get how I can assign the existing suburb Id to the Address table, column SuburbId ??